# Using haar classifier for detecting a face

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

He guys,

I wrote a piece code which should detect my face from a cam. But when I run it, it says: segmentation error. I don't know what's wrong so if you could take a look. Here's my code:

```
  String fn_haar = "./haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml";
    CascadeClassifier haar_cascade;
    haar_cascade.load(fn_haar);

vector< Rect_<int> > bodys;
haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(input, bodys);//, 1.1, 3, 0, Size(100,100), Size());
cv::Mat body;

Rect body_i = bodys[0];
if(!bodys.empty())
{
    Rect body_i = bodys[0];
    body = input(body_i);
    imshow("body", body);
    waitKey(0);
}
```

The input is an image from a cam.

Comment: What line does the error occur on? Have you used a debugger? Right now you haven't posted enough information for others to give you good help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Rect body_i = bodys[0];
if(!bodys.empty())
{ ...
```

see, you're accessing bodys[0] before checking if it's empty (well, *if* it's empty, it *will* crash )

you don't even need that line of code there, do you ?

also please check the cascade-loading, to avoid further 'surprises':

```
bool loaded = haar_cascade.load(fn_haar);
if ( ! loaded ) 
{ // whaa, check the path again. }
```

Comment: I did not need that code there no. My mistake. The problem lies with the loading of the cascade. this does not work. trying to figure it out now